# Pyspark - Create Equivalent of Business current view in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create an equivalent of bussiness current view in pyspark , I have an history file and a delta file(containing id and date) .I need to create final dataframe which will have the single record for each id and that record should be of latest date .

```
df1=sql_context.createDataFrame([("3000", "2017-04-19"), ("5000", "2017-04-19"), ("9012", "2017-04-19")], ["id", "date"])
df2=sql_context.createDataFrame([("3000", "2017-04-18"), ("5120", "2017-04-18"), ("1012", "2017-04-18")], ["id", "date"])
```

df3=df2.union(df1).distinct()

```
+----+----------+
|  id|      date|
+----+----------+
|3000|2017-04-19|
|3000|2017-04-18|
|5120|2017-04-18|
|5000|2017-04-19|
|1012|2017-04-18|
|9012|2017-04-19|
```

+----+----------+

I tried doing a union and do a distinct , it gives me id=3000 for both the dates where as I need only record for id=300 for date=2017-04-19

Even subtract doesnt work since it returns all the rows of either of the df's .

Desired output:-

```
+----+----------+
|  id|      date|
+----+----------+
|3000|2017-04-19|
|
|5120|2017-04-18|
|5000|2017-04-19|
|1012|2017-04-18|
|9012|2017-04-19|
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp, col, to_date, max

#sample data
df1=sqlContext.createDataFrame([("3000", "2017-04-19"),
                                ("5000", "2017-04-19"),
                                ("9012", "2017-04-19")],
                               ["id", "date"])
df2=sqlContext.createDataFrame([("3000", "2017-04-18"),
                                ("5120", "2017-04-18"),
                                ("1012", "2017-04-18")],
                               ["id", "date"])
df=df2.union(df1)
df.show()

#convert 'date' column to date type so that latest date can be fetched for an ID
df = df.\
    withColumn('date_inDateFormat',to_date(unix_timestamp(col('date'),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("timestamp"))).\
    drop('date')

#get latest date for an ID
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(max('date_inDateFormat').alias('date'))
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----+----------+
|  id|      date|
+----+----------+
|5000|2017-04-19|
|1012|2017-04-18|
|5120|2017-04-18|
|9012|2017-04-19|
|3000|2017-04-19|
+----+----------+
```

**Note:** Please don't forget to [let SO know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if the answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Prem , It definately works and pyspark drop duplicate function works too .

Comment: Glad that it helped :)